# Python - Outputting two data sets (lists?) to data file as two columns

Tags: python

I am very novice when it comes to python. I have done most of my programming in C++. I have a program which generates the fast Fourier transform of a data set and plots both the data and the FFT in two windows using matplotlib. Instead of plotting, I want to output the data to a file. This would be a simple task for me in C++, but I can't seem to figure this out in python. So the question is, "how can I output powerx and powery to a data file in which both data sets are in separate columns? Below is the program:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from fft import fft
from fft import fft_power
from numpy import array
import math
import time


# data downloaded from ftp://ftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/ccg/co2/trends/co2_mm_mlo.txt
print ' C02 Data from Mauna Loa'
data_file_name = 'co2_mm_mlo.txt'
file = open(data_file_name, 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
print ' read', len(lines), 'lines from', data_file_name

window = False

yinput = []
xinput = []

for line in lines :
    if line[0] != '#' :
        try:
            words = line.split()
            xval = float(words[2])
            yval = float( words[4] )
            yinput.append( yval )
            xinput.append( xval )
        except ValueError :
            print 'bad data:',line


N = len(yinput)
log2N = math.log(N, 2)
if log2N - int(log2N) > 0.0 :
    print 'Padding with zeros!'
    pads = [300.0] * (pow(2, int(log2N)+1) - N)
    yinput = yinput + pads
    N = len(yinput)
    print 'Padded : '
    print len(yinput)
    # Apply a window to reduce ringing from the 2^n cutoff
    if window : 
        for iy in xrange(len(yinput)) :
            yinput[iy] = yinput[iy] * (0.5 - 0.5 * math.cos(2*math.pi*iy/float(N-1)))

y = array( yinput ) 
x = array([ float(i) for i in xrange(len(y)) ] )
Y = fft(y)

powery = fft_power(Y)
powerx = array([ float(i) for i in xrange(len(powery)) ] )

Yre = [math.sqrt(Y[i].real**2+Y[i].imag**2) for i in xrange(len(Y))]


plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot( x, y )

ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
p1, = plt.plot( powerx, powery )
p2, = plt.plot( x, Yre )
ax.legend( [p1, p2], ["Power", "Magnitude"] )
plt.yscale('log')


plt.show()
```

Comment: Quite a bit of array/list objects here. Which ones do you want to write to file? yinput? xinput? y? x? powery? powerx?

Comment: The four things that I would want written to a file are the four things being plotted: powerx, powery, x, Yre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a csv.writer() to achieve this task, here is the reference: https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/csv.html

Basic usage:

zip you lists into rows:

```
rows=zip(powery,powerx)
```

Use a csv writer to write the data to a csv file:

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This worked and was what I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Comment: Please vote it and mark it as answer; so that future visitors are aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can write data from two different lists into text file in two column.

```
# Two random lists
index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
value = [4.5, 5, 7.0, 11, 15.7]

# Opening file for output
file_name = "output.txt"
fwm = open(file_name, 'w')

# Writing data in file
for i in range(len(index)):
    fwm.write(str(index[i])+"\t")
    fwm.write(str(value[i])+"\n")

# Closing file after writing
fwm.close()
```

if your list contain data in the form of string then remove 'str' while writing data in file.

If you want to save data in csv file change

> fwm.write(str(index[i])+"\t")
>
> WITH
>
> fwm.write(str(index[i])+",")

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to use the file for, I'd suggest either the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) module or the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html?highlight=json.dump#json.dump) module.

Writing the file as CSV data will give you the ability to open it with a spreadsheet, graph it, edit it, etc.

Writing the file as JSON data will give you the ability to quickly import it into other programming languages, and to inspect it (generally read-only -- if you want to do serious editing, go with CSV).